# How can I capture a screenshot with AutoIt executed remotely via PsExec?

Tags: screenshot, autoit, psexec

I have to run an AutoIt script which does some actions and takes screenshots (using `_ScreenCapture_Capture()`) of these actions. 
If I run the AutoIt script on my Windows machine the screenshots are taken perfectly.
The problem I have now is that I have to start the AutoIt script remotely using PsExec. The actions are executed fine, it is just that the screenshots are captured as black rectangles.

I assume that the problem is that PsExec will run my script in the non-interactive session 0 and not on the user's desktop. Is there a way to solve this problem and get appropriate screenshots?

Comment: I haven't tried, but some results on google seem to imply that `Send("{PRINTSCREEN}")` still works, might be worth it to try that and then save the file using code like [this](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/115672-save-clipboard-image-to-jpg-file/?p=807792).

Comment: Do any of [these flags](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-creates-black-windows_topic24466.html) help?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the link with the flags. So yes, using the following combination solved my problem and I was able to get correct screenshots: `psexec \\computername -u <domain name\user name> -p <your password>  -i  <your session ID> cmd /c start <your application>` . But as a precondition it is necessary to have an open (visual) connection to the host (e.g. using `rdesktop`) otherwise the script won't run.

Answer (score -1):

_ScreenCapture_Capture needs the window you want to capture to be visible and active. Try WinActivate(...).

Comment: I have already WinActivate() in my script. I don't think it is a problem of the window not being activated because the window is opening in the non-interactive desktop sesson 0 when running the script from Cygwin.